# I can't reach route api/v2/ExternalCodes using RouteAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC website with Web Api 2 also, C# and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I'm trying to do versioning but I'm doing something wrong.

I have created a new version of my controller in a new namespace:

```
namespace MyProject.Web.API.Controllers.v2
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ActionLogFilter]
    public class ExternalCodesController : ApiController
    {
        public ExternalCodesController()
        {
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/v2/ExternalCodes")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            [ ... ]
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/v2/ExternalCodes")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(
            byte? codeLevel,
            int batchId,
            int? lineId,
            int productId,
            string startingCode,
            int? quantity)
        {
            [ ... ]
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I do a GET using this URI: `http://myHost:53827/api/v2/ExternalCodes?codeLevel=&batchId=5&lineId=&productId=7&startingCode=&quantity=` I get a `NotFound` HTTP status code. But I have also tested this URI: `http://myHost:53827/api/v2/ExternalCodes` with the same status code.

What am I doing wrong?

My `WebApiConfig.cs` is:

```
namespace MyProject.Web.API
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class to config Web API routes and filters.
    /// </summary>
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Json configuration
            var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            // Remove formatting to make json smaller.
            json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None; 

            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // Filters.
            config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
            config.Filters.Add(new UnhandledExceptionFilter());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your route config look like? have you got a default route (as well as attribute routing)

Comment: @Alex I have edit my question with WebApiConfig file.

Comment: try commenting out the "DefaultApi" routes registration (convention based routes)... just want to see if that works

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @VansFannel I added your class to an existing project that I have, compiled, then invoked the action with the url provided changing only the port number. The action method was invoked! I don't know what the problem is that you are having but I don't believe that it is in your controller or your route attribute. I literally used the uri http://localhost:6137/api/v2/ExternalCodes?codeLevel=&batchId=5&lineId=&productId=7&startingCode=&quantity=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has actually happened to me before. It was due to having two controllers with the same name inside the root 'Controllers' folder, regardless of sub-directories and namespaces (this behavior is different inside areas). Try renaming the controllers to something like:

```
ExternalCodesV1Controller
```

and

```
ExternalCodesV2Controller
```

You should be able to keep the namespaces and even attribute routes the same.

Answer (score 0):

A nasty solution for your reference. The idea is to change the default controller selector to your custom one.

file 'ValuesController.cs':

```
namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }        
    }
}
```

file 'ValuesV2Controller.cs':

```
namespace WebApplication4.Controllers.V2
{    
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value3", "value4" };
        }
    }
}
```

create a custom controller selector:

```
public class MyHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
    {
        private HttpConfiguration _config;

        public MyHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
        {
            _config = configuration;
        }

        public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var routeData = request.GetRouteData();
            var routeTemplate = routeData.Route.RouteTemplate;
            if (routeTemplate.IndexOf("v2/values") != -1)
            {
                return new HttpControllerDescriptor(
                    _config, "Values", 
                    typeof(WebApplication4.Controllers.V2.ValuesController));
            } else if (routeTemplate.IndexOf("values") != -1)
            {
                return new HttpControllerDescriptor(
                    _config, "Values",
                    typeof(WebApplication4.Controllers.ValuesController));
            }
            return base.SelectController(request);
        }
    }
```

Register the custom controller selector in the file 'WebApiConfig.cs':

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "route1",
                routeTemplate: "values"
                );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "route2",
                routeTemplate: "v2/values");

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );          

            config.Services.Replace(
                typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), 
                new MyHttpControllerSelector(config));
        }
    }
```

So when you use url like 'http://localhost:13839/values', you get  value1 and value2. And value3 and value4 for url 'http://localhost:13839/v2/values'.